# GWT event that should be fired whenever textbox.setText() is called

Tags: html, gwt

I am using GWT textbox.

Whenever textbox.setText() method is called, i want to perform an action in some other class.

ValueChangeEvent is not fired whenever setText() is called.

Is there any event that will be fired or any ways to achieve this?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use [setValue(String value, boolean fireEvent) method](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#setValue%28T,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Cool :) But your link points to the method that doesn't take a boolean on event firing. [This](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#setValue(T, boolean) ) is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the `TextBox.seText()` method, you'll see that, all the way down to the actual DOM, no event is ever generated, so what you want to do simply won't work off-the-box.

I see two options:

1. Whenever *you* call setText, you also call the event handler of your choice or, much better
2. Make your own TextBox that extends TextBox, and override the setText() method so that it first calls super.setText() and *then* does whatever event generation you'd like

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is i can't go with approach 2. I want a generic handler. 
But from what you say, it looks not possible to register for events.

Comment: Well, I just went through setText() and there's no even being triggered so, no, no event subscriptions with vanilla `TextBox` instances. Check out @DvdPrd answer with setValue though